# Python to give process id of subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, subprocess

Im using python3 on ubuntu 18. 
I have a python code to run some ansible playbooks, i want my code to give me some id \ process id
of the current runing process and when it is finished.

for example this code :

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["ansible-playbook", "-i", "hosts", "playbook.yml"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

can this release some process id and also to let me know when this proc id is finished \ closed?
I looked for a way with multiprocessing and threads but it seems like it is just does not fit
Thanks.

**EDIT: i need the subproc ID when it start, not when subproc already done.
process.pid gives ID after it is done**

Comment: just `process.pid`. And use `process.wait()` and `process.poll() is not None` (non blocking)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  process.pid it does gives an ID but AFTER the subproc is done, i need to know it on the starting of the subprocess, and also the process.wait() process.poll()  commes after it has finnished..

Comment: Figurd how to use it, sorry:
    `while loop is True:
        if process.poll() is None:
            print("PID:", procPid)
            loop = False`

Comment: or `while True: if process.poll() is None: break`